# Possibility to get GitHub release notes as plain text URL?

Tags: github, release

I need to extract content from a project's GitHub release notes, in automated fashion.
The surrounding HTML content of the website is not needed and tends to complicate parsing.

Does GitHub provide a plain text URL for the release notes (similar to the raw view for files), or do I have to work with the HTML anyway?

Comment: You could use the REST API: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-releases

Comment: @knittl could you please elaborate how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Call

```bash
# substitute placeholders accordingly ($OWNER $REPO $TAG)
curl -L "https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/releases/tags/$TAG"
```

and extract the `name` and `body` keys from the returned JSON.

Comment: If calling this from a programming language one can of course use a native web library rather than `curl`.

Comment: Doc link: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-release-by-tag-name